# new method for solving ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Can you please help me with this question?

In order to build the new method for solving ODE $y '(x)=f(x,y(x))$, we use an integration formula:
$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\approx (b-a)f\left ( \frac{a+b}{2} \right ) $

Show that this method can be introduced by:
$y_{n+1}=y_{n}+h\cdot f\left ( x_{n}+\frac{h}{2}, y_{n}+\frac{h}{2} f(x_{n},y_{n}) \right)$

Hint: Taylor series.

$h=b-a$

Thank you!

Comment: What is $y_0$ (or $y_1$) and what is $h$?

Comment: I would assume the OP is asked to solve $\dot{y} = f(x,y)$, and is trying to discretize with step size $h$. But it would be better if s/he can confirm this.

Comment: @ Willie Wong Yes, you are absolutely right

Comment: Are the $f$ in $y'=f(x,y)$ and the $f$ in $\int f dx$ the same or is the integration formula written in general? And what do you mean with introduced?

Comment: @  macydanim Yes I guess, i mean that this is the discretization